# Return Max(Recent_Date) for each month, Duplicate value and inner join issue - SQL

Tags: sql, date, inner-join, max

Basically, I want to achieve , for each months, like in this example, from January until March 2013, what is the Max(Most_Recent_Day) for each users.

Example, From January to March, every month in the Database, systems will capture the Most_Recent_Day for each users.

Below are the expected results:

```
User                 | Most_Recent_Day
--------------------------------
afolabi.banu         | 1/31/2013
afolabi.banu         | 2/7/2013
afolabi.banu         | 3/21/2013
mario.sapiter        | 1/22/2013
mario.sapiter        | 2/7/2013
mario.sapiter        | 3/11/2013
```

However, I want to have another DB column as well to be display .Below is the column.

```
User|Total_Hits | Recent_Month| Most_Recent_Day | Most_Recent_Days_Hits
```

I tried to use inner join, but the result are not what i expect. I got duplicated user name and duplicated recent day. Basically, I want only to display no duplicated record for the same user name.

Below is the result that I got. Please ignore the recent_month value since it's data from database.

```
User          |Total_Hits | Recent_Month   | Most_Recent_Day | Most_Recent_Days_Hits
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
afolabi.banu  | 223   |   25       |   2/7/2013      |  5
afolabi.banu  | 223   |   25       |   2/7/2013      |  5
afolabi.banu  | 211   |   13       |   1/31/2013     |  3
afolabi.banu  | 223   |   25           |   2/7/2013      |  5
afolabi.banu  | 296   |   31       |   3/21/2013     |  1
afolabi.banu  | 296   |   31           |   3/21/2013     |  1
mario.sapiter | 95    |   7        |   2/7/2013      |  5
mario.sapiter | 7     |   7        |   3/21/2013     |  1
mario.sapiter | 7     |   37           |   3/22/2013     |  1
mario.sapiter | 249   |   37       |   2/7/2013      |  5
```

This is my SQL Code

```
SELECT t.[User],
t.Total_Hits,
t.Recent_Month,
t.Most_Recent_Day, 
t.Most_Recent_Day_Hits FROM UserUsageMonthly t
INNER JOIN 
(
select  
[User]
, max(Most_Recent_Day) as Most_Recent_Day
from UserUsageMonthly (NoLock)
where Application_Name='Daily Production Review' and Site_Collection='wrm13' 
and Most_Recent_Day between '1/1/2013' and '3/31/2013'  
group by [User], datepart(month,Most_Recent_Day) 
) table2
ON
t.[User]=table2.[User]
AND t.Most_Recent_Day = table2.Most_Recent_Day 
order by t.[User]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the month value to your SQL SELECT

```
SELECT 
MONTH(t.Most_Recent_Day) as 'MyMonth',
t.[User],
t.Total_Hits,
t.Recent_Month,
t.Most_Recent_Day, 
t.Most_Recent_Day_Hits FROM UserUsageMonthly t
```

Then you can group by the month column

```
GROUP BY MyMonth
```